# Using RowMapper to return Map<String,Map<String,List<Object>>>

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Each row in my DB is going to be like this

```
School  Class   StudentID   Name    Age
123      8        811       John    10
123      8        812       Smith   11
123      8        821       John    12
123      8        822       Smith   13
123      9        911       John    14
123      9        912       Smith   15
456      8        811       John    10
456      8        812       Smith   11
```

Now I want to return the above data like this

```
Map<String,Map<String,List<Object>>>

ie. Map<School,Map<Class,List<StudentID>>>
```

I am using Spring's `JdbcTemplate` with a `RowMapper` but all I can get is an List of all the rows. Since I wont be able to maintain my main Map in my RowMapper (*can I have a static map inside the RowMapper class ?? but I do not want it to be static as this is a webservice and subsequent calls might get screwed.*), I only have the option to get this Row list and then have my logic to create the Collection that I want.

I came to know about `ResultSetExtractor` but I could not find how to get this done using that.

Please let me know if there is any way I can get this done using a row mapper or some sort. Or my only way to solve this is my having to iterate the list again and get what I want.

**EDIT:** 
My query is a select query like this:

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME
```

and it actually takes 40 minutes to retrieve the ResultSet from Java.

Since the DB call is for filling the cache object which is done using CRON every 4 hours, I don't mind the time delay of 40 minutes since the actual REST calls, will be referring to the cache object. But still I want to do this as efficiently as possible.

Also please let me know if there is any other way I can handle this scenario. A normal jdbc call for every REST call wll be costly,since we will be getting 100's of requests per second.

Comment: I assume you have a `DAO` class for each of your entities? Why not let your DAO do the transformation of the `List` to the `Map` and return it to the outside world?

Comment: The jdbcTemplate call is inside the DAO, I want to know if this can be done using RowMapper.

Comment: So you basically want the `JdbcTemplate` to form the `Map` for you when you execute a query with it? I believe any solution you implement would eventually just be transforming a `List` to a `Map` internally so why not let your `DAO` do it?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want. But is there a way to do it or should I do it on my own from the List obtained from jdbcTemplate

Comment: I guess there should be a way to do it. But the question is what is your motivation behind doing it?

Comment: why not create dto for this?

Answer (score 2):

**RowMapper**

You could implement a state-full `RowMapper` that solves your problem, but it is not really conform with the idea of the `RowMapper` which is thought to be stateless and reusable like stated in the JavaDoc:

> ... RowMapper objects are typically stateless and thus reusable ...

The `RowMapper`is used for row to object conversion, which means each row of the *ResultSet* is getting an own *Object*.

**ResultSetExtractor**

It is really the `ResultSetExtractor` that fits your task. The `ResultSetExtractor` is made for *ResultSet* to Object conversion as you intend to do.

Just implement filling the Map there by iterating the *ResultSet* and pass an instance of the `ResultSetExtractor` implementation to your `JdbcTemplate.query(...)` call.

---

***Update 2017-02-09***

While following the comment that an example using `ResultSetExtractor` would be useful, I stumbled upon the `RowCallbackHandler` interface. While both options allow you to realize the wanted behavior, the `RowCallbackHandler` handles the `ResultSet` iteration for you. It can be used via `JdbcTemplate.query(...)` call as well.

For examples of both `RowCallbackHandler` and `ResultSetExtractor` I recommend the following article Ram Satish: http://www.javarticles.com//2015/02/example-of-spring-callbacks-used-in-jdbctemplate.html

Comment: Thanks. But is building my actual map right after I do the jdbc call efficient ? (performance wise.) The `SELECT * from TABLE` query that I am using actually takes 40 minutes in order to complete. And if I want to build the map again, I would have to iterate over the ResultSet again. And that's why thought this approach would help in performance.

Comment: I tried the ResultSetExtractor today and was able to do what I intended to do. Can you please add a small implementation snippet of how the ResultSetExtractor works so that the answer is more useful for others ?